# Cannot upload asp.net mvc dll files to web server, 'File in use error'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ftp

I've revisited my asp.net mvc core 2.0 web site after some 8 months and for some reason I cannot upload any dll files from my local published folder to the hosting server.  I keep getting the following error...

"Copying files to remote side failed.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

I get this error no matter which method I use, ftp or http.

What's changed in the last 8 months?

Comment: We need [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Please check list below:

1. Please ensure you have rights to access the file;
2. Please check if the FTP port is used by other applications;
3. Please check if the file is indeed used by other programs.
4. Please run process explorer and see what process is locking the file.

Also try:

- Restarting your visual studio
- Restarting your operating system.
- Restarting target server or Web Server.

Please provide more information for more help

Comment: 1. I have rights to the folder ( I am the sole user). 
2. I get the same via ftp or via http using the host's web app.
3. The destination file is a web dll. Would it be locked if someone has the web site open?
I've restarted everything but cannot restart host server